# PHP count div-s inside parent div, when add code depends of inside div-s summary

Tags: php, jquery, html

Need help with php code, that can count divs inside parent div and add some code if inner divs have specific count number.

Html is:

```
<div class="row-fluid str_category"> 
    <div class="span2 jshop_categ"><div>
    <div class="span2 jshop_categ"><div>
    <div class="span2 jshop_categ"><div>
    <div class="span2 jshop_categ"><div>
    <div class="span2 jshop_categ"><div>
</div>
```

So need php with logic something like:

```
find div with class.str_category
find div with class.jshop_categ
count number of divs.jshop_categ

if number of divs.jshop_categ = 4
- add code "<div class="additionaldiv"><div>"

if number of divs.jshop_categ = 3
- add code "<div class="additionaldiv"><div> <div class="additionaldiv"><div>"

if number of divs.jshop_categ = 3
- add code "<div class="additionaldiv"><div> <div class="additionaldiv"><div> <div class="additionaldiv"><div>"
```

--
Final result is to make always 5 divs in a row, even if only one div inside parent div.
Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried so far? What is your specific problem?

Comment: It would be helpful to show more than the pseudo code as it's unclear at the moment how this new code would fit in.  Are you getting the HTML using some form of HTML parser or is the HTML being built in your code.

Comment: HTML built in my code. I can`t give exmples of working parts of php code because all of them not giving result, and i bad at php.

Comment: If you don't show us the code, we can't help you fix it...

Answer (score 0):

Why not just make a loop that will always display 5 inner `<div>` ?

So the code will be:

```
<div class="row-fluid str_category"> 
    <?php 
        for($i=0; $i<5; $i++){
            echo '<div class="span2 jshop_categ">yeah<div>';
        }
    ?>
</div>
```

***If this is not what you really want, please elaborate the situation further :)